# If statement for page navigation

Tags: php, if-statement, filter, navigation, compare

I am trying to figure out a way to show a Page Navigation but only if there are more then 30 items, because the limit for 1 page is max 30 items. If there are more then 30 items it should show a page navigation to the next list with max 30 items and so on...(0-30, 30-60, 60-90...)

```
if($this->quantity_selected_rows >= $this->items_per_page && $this->quantity_total_rows > $this->items_per_page)
{show navigation}
else
{dont show navigation}

e.g. 
quantity_selected_rows = 30
items_per_page = 100
quantity_total_rows = 30

for clarity:

if(30>=30 && 100 > 30)
{show navigation}
else
{dont show navigation}
```

My Problem is that if i filter my grid and it would EXACTLY give me 30 filtered items it will show the page navigation according to my statement, which is bad.

Is there a better way to describe this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i got you wrong, but you just have to adjust the if condition:

`30>=30` evaluates to true, which is why a result of 30 filtered items would show the page navigation (at least in your example with total items 100)

The code below does the following:

If there are **exactly** 30 in your filtered result   => no page navigation
If there are **less than** 30 in your filtered result => no page navigation
If there are **more than** 30 in your filtered result => show page navigation

Since I assume:

> If there are 30 items in the filtered result the total items have to
> be at least 30 as well

you can also shorten the if condition:

```
if($selectedRows > $itemsPerPage) {
    //Show navigation
} else {
    //Don't show
}
```

Had to change your variables to make it executable in the snippet and also more readible.
You can change this to use your values instead of the hardcoded numbers.

```
<?php

$selectedRows = 30;  //Result of filtering the grid
$itemsPerPage = 30;  //maximum amount of items per page
$totalRows    = 100; //Unfiltered grid

if($selectedRows > $itemsPerPage)
echo "Show navigation";
else
echo "Don't show navigation";
```

https://3v4l.org/rlHYV

Please tell me if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The thing is that there is a max of 30 items in a page. So even if there are more then 30 items the navigation wont show. So for your exampleif($selectedRows > $itemsPerPage) {
    //Do something
} it wont show the navigation

Comment: same for if($selectedRows > $itemsPerPage && $totalRows > $itemsPerPage)
echo "Show navigation";
else
echo "Don't show navigation";

Comment: to clarify: if(30 >= 30) it should show the navigation. But if i filter the grid and there are exactly 30 items filtered the navigation shouldn't show.

Comment: I hope you understand my point :P The problem is the filtering and getting exactly 30 results

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. So `$selectedRows` is not the result of the filtering?
Where does the filtering happen then? You need to include that code too.
Or is this happening on the frontend, you'd need javascript to hide the navigation then.

Comment: Yes I already got that but you need to clarify: 1. What is `$selectedRows` refering to if it's not the result of your filtering. 2. Where is the filtering you are talking about happening -> need that code to help you.

Comment: yes $selectedRows is the filter. The number of filtered items will be stored in $selectedRows

Comment: Ok i found my mistake. Sorry to bother. FYI i made another statement if($this->quantity_selected_rows%$this->items_per_page == 0){}